# dynamic function cant be assing to the parameter type void function

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
Widget DefaultFormField({
  double height = 50,
  required TextEditingController controller,
  required TextInputType keyBoardType,
  Function(String)? onSubmit,
  Function(String)? onValidate,
  Function()? onChange,
  IconData? suffix,
  required String? text,
  bool isPassword = false,
}) =>
    Container(
        height: height,
        child: TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit,
          onChanged: onChange,
          controller: controller,
          validator: onValidate,
          keyboardType: keyBoardType,
        ));
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: when i tried to u use the onValidated function doesnt work and  give me that error The argument type 'dynamic Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void

Answer (score 0):

You need add callback dataType and return data type like bellow.

```dart
Widget DefaultFormField({
  double height = 50,
  required TextEditingController controller,
  required TextInputType keyBoardType,
  Function(String)? onSubmit,
  String Function(String?)? onValidate,
  Function(String)? onChange,
  IconData? suffix,
  required String? text,
  bool isPassword = false,
}) =>
    Container(
        height: height,
        child: TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit,
          onChanged: onChange,
          controller: controller,
          validator: onValidate,
          keyboardType: keyBoardType,
        ));
```

Comment: didn't notice that option,

Comment: Widget DefaultFormField({
  double height = 50,
   required TextEditingController controller,
   required TextInputType keyBoardType,
 Function(String )? onSubmit,
 Function(String)? onValidate,
  Function()? onChange,
  IconData? suffix,
   required String? text,
  bool isPassword = false,
}) =>
    Container(
      height: height,
      child: TextFormField(
        // onFieldSubmitted: onSubmitted
        onChanged: onChange,
        controller: controller,
        validator: onValidate,
        keyboardType: keyBoardType,

Comment: the problem is in the functions

Comment: Ok, got it, check the update snippet